# Seemingly Random 'Permission Denied' response from firebase after (successful) user authentication

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm going to preface this by saying I'm using the Firebase Unity plugin (most recent master) and the most recent Facebook plugin.

So i use 2 methods of authentication for Firebase.
Facebook and Email/Password.
I have the SSO set up on facebook..and about 50% of the time..everything works great.
User logs in after receiving a token and we're off and running.
The other 50% of the time...
The user can authenticate just fine..I receive a log statement with the UID for Firebase.
The first operation after a successful auth is to read their user data from the database. This is where things fail half the time.
Some times I receive the data just fine and go on my merry way. Some times I fail with a fault. Its a very generic permission denied error (which doesnt make sense because the get request is done after the auth callback (which is what supplies the uid for me to use).
Has anyone run into anything similar?
My database rules are dead simple

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I even got to a point where I put in an artificial 2 second delay after successful authentication and trying to do a read; still no luck.

This is also a very new (within the past 3 days) issue.
I had a alpha test a week ago and everything was working very smoothly.

-I tried deleting the linked android app and re-creating it thinking something was fishy with the google-services.json
-I tried wiping all data/users/logins from the database

Still no luck